# Test firewall rules (Linux)

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a question about how to test the firewall rules. To be more specific, for academic purpose I have to set up a machine which will accept all kind of packets o a specific interface.

I added an IP Table rule:

```
sudo iptables –A INPUT –i eth0 –j ACCEPT
```

I need a practical prove that this interface accept all kind of packets.
Does anyone know a specific way or tool which can help me.
I can't find anything better than

```
nmap -p 80 <ipAddress>
```

or

```
nmap - sU <ipAddress>
```

Or maybe somebody can propose a better solution to prove that the interface accepts all kind of packets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most cases doing an `nmap -p 0-65535 -PN <ip>` works well for testing a remote firewall's TCP rulesets.  If you want something more advanced you can use a [packet crafter](http://sectools.org/tag/packet-crafters/) like [hping](http://www.hping.org/) which is designed to test firewall rulesets.  [Here](http://wiki.hping.org/94) is some information on building packets with hping.

Answer (score 3):

You can also implement logging function in your iptables using -j LOG option and modifying your OS to generate a log file, I do this for new installation of PBX.

```
iptables -N SIP-Firewall
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -s 110.10.0.0/255.255.255.0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -s 204.9.161.164 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -s 63.209.144.201 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -s 66.54.140.46 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -m string --string "tel:" --algo bm --to 65 -j DROP
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -m string --string "OPTIONS sip:" --algo bm --to 65 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -m string --string "INVITE sip:" --algo bm --to 65 -m hashlimit --hashlimit 4/min --hashlimit-burst 1 --hashlimit-mode srcip,dstport --hashlimit-name sip_i_limit -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -m string --string "REGISTER sip:" --algo bm --to 65 -m hashlimit --hashlimit 2/min --hashlimit-burst 1 --hashlimit-mode srcip,dstport --hashlimit-name sip_r_limit -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -m hashlimit --hashlimit 10/min --hashlimit-burst 1 --hashlimit-mode srcip,dstport --hashlimit-name sip_o_limit -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -j LOG
iptables -A SIP-Firewall -j DROP



vi /etc/syslog.conf
kern.warning /var/log/iptables.log
service syslog restart
```

Some info here:

http://openvz.org/Traffic_accounting_with_iptables